# MVC controller query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Following is my cascasde dropdown list query. Countries list loading up but non of the states loading up in my dropdown list. if someone can help me to rectify the query please.

```
        public ActionResult CountryList()
        {

            var countries = db.Countries.OrderBy(x=>x.CountryName).ToList(); 
        //    IQueryable countries = Country.GetCountries();

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(
                            countries,
                            "CountryID",
                            "CountryName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );
            }

            return View(countries);
        }

        public ActionResult StateList(int CountryID)
        {
            IQueryable <State> states= db.States. Where(x => x.CountryID == CountryID);

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new SelectList(
                                states,
                                "StateID",
                                "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );

            return View(states);
        }
```

following is the View file also containg java script:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Dropdown/Countries/List",function (data) {
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    items += "<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Countries").html(items);
            });

            $("#Countries").change(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Dropdown/States/List/" + $("#Countries > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                    var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#States").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label for="Countries">Countries</label>
    <select id="Countries" name="Countries"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <label for="States">States</label>
    <select id="States" name="States"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your javascript code that execute ajax calls?

Comment: Call .ToList() method on your states object

Comment: IQueryable <State> states= db.States. Where(x => x.CountryID == CountryID).ToList();           ...... this code showing red line

Comment: What stops you from using `$('#Countries').val();`?

Comment: When you call .ToList(), that is not IQueryable, thats gonna be IEnumerable. Just use var states=

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your action method name is `StateList` which expects a parameter named `CountryID`. But your code is not making a call to your `StateList` action method with such a querystring param. So fix that.

```
$("#Countries").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("StateList","Home")?CountryID=" + 
                                                $("#Countries").val(), function (data) {
        var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
            items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#States").html(items);
    });
});
```

I also used `@Url.Action` helper method to get the correct url to the action method with the assumption that your `StateList` action method belongs to `HomeController`. Update the parameter according to your real controller name as needed.

Now, In your action method, you should not try to return the IQueryable collection, you may simply project the data to a list of `SelectListItem` and return that.

```
public ActionResult StateList(int CountryID)
{
    var states = db.States.Where(x => x.CountrId==CountryID).ToList(); 
    //this ToList() call copies the data to a new list variable.

    var stateOptions = states.Select(f => new SelectListItem { 
                                                         Value = f.StateID.ToString(), 
                                                         Text = f.StateName }
                                    ).ToList();

    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(stateOptions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return View(states);
}
```